# "Run" can get the answer but debug will throw Segmentation fault in codeblocks

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

This is not the first time i meet the problem. Sometimes the code can execute successfully when you "Run" it, but failed in the "Debug" mode.

**"Run" mode:**
[image]

**"Debug" mode:**
[image]

When use "Run" mode, it will get the result:
[image]

But when use "Debug" mode, it will throw the error.
[image]

Here is the code. thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define N 50
#define DEBUG 1
int* power2[4*N];
int* save[4*N];
int tmp_n1[2*N], tmp_n2[2*N];
#define trim(a,n) do{ \
        int n_ = n; \
        for(i=1;i<=n_;i++) if(a[i]>=10){ \
            a[i+1] += a[i] / 10; \
            a[i] %= 10; \
        } \
        while(a[n_+1] != 0) n_++; \
        a[0] = n_; \
    }while(0)

#define trim2(a,n) do{ \
        int n_ = n; \
        for(i=n_;i>=1;i--) if(a[i]<0){ \
            a[i+1] += (a[i]-9) / 10; \
            a[i] -= (a[i]-9) / 10 * 10; \
        } \
        while(a[n_] == 0 && n_>0) n_--; \
        a[0] = n_; \
    }while(0)

#define print(a) do{ \
    int i1; \
    if(a[0] == 0) putchar('0');\
    for(i1=a[0];i1>=1;i1--) putchar(a[i1]+'0');\
    putchar('\n');\
}while(0)

#define copy(dest,src) memcpy(dest,src,2*N*sizeof(int))
#define clear(src) memset(src,0,2*N*sizeof(int))
void sum(int* a,int* b,int* c){
    int i; int n = max(a[0],b[0]);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    trim(c,n);
}
void minus(int* a,int* b,int* c){
    int i; int n = a[0];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[i]=a[i]-b[i];
    trim2(c,n);
}
void minusn(int* a,int n,int *c){
    int i;
    if(c != a) for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++) c[i]=a[i];
    c[1] -= n;
    trim2(c,a[0]);
}
void sumn(int* a,int n,int *c){
    int i;
    if(c != a) for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++) c[i]=a[i];
    c[1] += n;
    trim(c,a[0]);
}
void timen(int* a,int n,int* c){
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++) c[i]=a[i]*n;
    trim(c,a[0]);
}
void time(int*a,int*b,int*c){
    if(a == c || b == c) printf("time no allow eq."), exit(-1);
    int i,j;
    clear(c);
    for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++) for(j=1;j<=b[0];j++)
    c[i+j-1] += a[i]*b[j];
    trim(c,a[0]+b[0]-1);
}
void setn(int* a,int n){
    int i=0;
    while(n != 0){
        a[++i] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    a[0]=i;
}
int bigger(int*a,int*b){ // a>=b
    if(a[0] != b[0]) return a[0]-b[0];
    int i = a[0];
    while(i>0 && a[i] == b[i]) i--;
    return a[i]-b[i];
}
int eq(int* a,int* b){
    return bigger(a,b) == 0;
}
int* getNewOne(){
    return (int*) calloc(2*N,sizeof(int));
}
void freeNewOne(int* p){
    free(p);
}
void qiuhe(int* a, int* b, int* c){ // aÊ×Ïî bÄ©Ïî
    // c = (a+b)*(b-a+1)/2;
    int* head = getNewOne();
    sum(a,b,head);
    int* nail = getNewOne();
    minus(b,a,nail);
    sumn(nail,1,nail);
    time(head,nail,c);

    int i, j =c[0];
    for(i=c[0];i>=1;i--){
        c[i-1] += (c[i] & 1) * 10;
        c[i] >>= 1;
    }

    while(c[j] == 0 && j>0) j--;
    c[0]=j;
}
int eqn(int*a,int n){
    if(a[0] > 1) return false;
    return a[1] == n;
}

void f(int* start, int* output){
    if(DEBUG){
        printf("Enter:");
        print(start);
    }
    if(eqn(start,0) || eqn(start,1) || eqn(start,2)) { setn(output,0); return; }

    int saveId = -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4*N;i++) if(bigger(power2[i],start)>=0) break;

        if(eq(power2[i],start)){
            if(save[i] != NULL){
                copy(output, save[i]);
                return;
            }
            saveId = i;
        }
        i--;
    int* s_p2 = getNewOne(); minus(start,power2[i],s_p2);
    int* o1 = getNewOne(), * o2 = getNewOne(), * o3;
        f(power2[i], o1);
        f(s_p2, o2);
        o3 = o2;

    int* head = getNewOne(); minusn(power2[i],1,head);
    int* nail = getNewOne(); minus(power2[i], s_p2, nail);
    int* tri = output; qiuhe(nail,head,tri); //(power2[i]-1 + power2[i]-o2) * (power2[i]-o2) / 2;

    free(head); free(nail);

    sum(tri, o1, tri);
    sum(tri, o2, tri);
    sum(tri, o3, tri);

    free(o1); free(o2); free(o3);
    if(saveId != -1){
        save[saveId] = getNewOne();
        copy(save[saveId], output);
    }
}
char sss[N];
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    power2[0] = getNewOne();
    setn(power2[0],1);
    for(i=1;i<4*N;i++){
        power2[i] = getNewOne();
        timen(power2[i-1],2,power2[i]);
        //print(power2[i]);
    }

    int* start =getNewOne();
    if(0){
        gets(sss);
        int n = strlen(sss);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) start[i]=sss[n-i]-'0';
        start[0]=n;
        sumn(start,1,start);
    }
    setn(start,1000000);

    int* output = getNewOne();
    f(start, output);
    print(output);
    //print(start);
    //printf("%d\n",-11/10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, all the problems are basically code problem.

I pass to a same pointer to the free(void*) function twice.